# How do I create levels for my puzzle game ? Obj-C & Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, levels

I want to create levels in my cocos2d game and I do not know how to do that with .plist files ... I searched the Internet but unfortunately I couldn't find significant information on how to implement these property lists. Can you please help out ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/). Tiled's TMX format is supported by Cocos2D.

As with any Apple technologies, the first place you should start searching for is the developer.apple.com website. In this case, here's the [Property List (plist) Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html).

However, I find property lists very awkward to work with, specifically if you want to create them manually and whenever they contain more than just a few entries. It certainly can't hurt to evaluate rolling out your own file format, text-based plain and simple. I would always rather work with simple text files like these rather than messing with property lists:

```
X=10;Y=10;Tile=30;
X=12;Y=11;Tile=28;
X=16;Y=19;Tile=22;
```

It's a different story if you actually design the data with a tool or within an app, where you'll be able to make use of the various collection convenience methods that save and load property lists, for example to and from a dictionary or array.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use tiles, as I am not using them. I  use simple sprites which basically don't move at all. I neither have a clue how to use plist files nor how to store my level data in CCScenes... That is why I am asking...